# Login screen is completely scrambled

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, graphics, login, multiple-monitors

I was happily using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS the other day, not a single issue. However, I got two new monitors and hooked them up to my graphics card.

After a reboot, I can no longer get into Ubuntu via normal, `nomodeset` or recovery modes.

In normal mode, at the moment when the login screen is supposed to appear, I get this:

[image: Egg Scramble]

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening simply from new monitors? What troubleshooting steps should I try?

My graphics card is quite old, its an XFX (now AMD) Radeon HD 7870.

Cheers.

Edit: BIOS and Grub are both working normally. Graphics are working normally in Windows 10 (I am dual-booting)

Comment: Have you tried to change VGA/DVI/HDMI Cable ? And is the BIOS screen normal?

Comment: @MatsK BIOS and Grub both normal. Not tried changing the cables but system is working in Windows 10 (I am dual booting)

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the comment.

Comment: @MatsK updated.

Comment: What kind of cable are you using? It's possible this is something failing related to HDCP.

Comment: They are both HDMI and both showing this, which makes me think it's not cable related